# Stuck on basic Linq to XML query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to extract the information from the namecheap sandbox api and can't figure out why my linq queries aren't working.

Here's a sample response.

**XML**

```
<ApiResponse Status="OK" xmlns="http://api.namecheap.com/xml.response">
  <Errors />
  <Warnings />
  <RequestedCommand>namecheap.domains.check</RequestedCommand>
  <CommandResponse>
    <DomainCheckResult Domain="google.com" Available="false" />
  </CommandResponse>
  <Server>WEB1-SANDBOX1</Server>
  <GMTTimeDifference>--4:00</GMTTimeDifference>
  <ExecutionTime>0.875</ExecutionTime>
</ApiResponse>
```

**C#**

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(url);
var response = (
    from  r in doc.Root.Descendants("ApiResponse") 
    where 1==1
    select new  { 
        Errors = r.Element("Errors").Value,
        Warnings = r.Element("Warnings").Value,
        RequestedCommand = r.Element("RequestedCommand").Value,
        CommandResponse = r.Element("CommandResponse").Value,
        Server = r.Element("Server").Value
    }
);
```

I've also tried this query with the same doc just to see if a simple example worked.

```
var test = doc.Descendants("RequestedCommand").First().Value;
```

But both return null. So where am I going wrong? I'll eventually need to get at the top level elements and the deeper elements within CommandResponse. Any help with that would also be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

As Jon's answer mentioned, it was mainly an issue with not using the namespace when referencing the various elements. Also used doc.Elements() rather then doc.Root. Descendants().

Here's an updated working version.

```
XNamespace ns = "http://api.namecheap.com/xml.response";
var response = (
    from r in doc.Elements()
    select new
    {
        Errors = r.Element(ns + "Errors").Value,
        Warnings = r.Element(ns + "Warnings").Value,
        RequestedCommand = r.Element(ns + "RequestedCommand").Value,
        CommandResponse = r.Element(ns + "CommandResponse").Value,
        Server = r.Element(ns + "Server").Value
    }
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using the namespace when you're looking for elements, descendants etc:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://api.namecheap.com/xml.response";
var doc = XDocument.Load(url);
var response = doc.Root
                  .Descendants(ns + "ApiResponse")
                  .Select(r => new {
                              Errors = r.Element(ns + "Errors").Value,
                              ...
                          });
```

(Note that you never need `where 1 == 1` in LINQ... I've changed this from query expression syntax as it wasn't giving you anything.)

The namespace is inherited from the `<ApiResponse>` element as the default namespace for all the other elements, as it's just `xmlns=...` rather than specifying an alias.

Also note that if you've shown us the *whole* XML document, then the above won't find any elements, as you're asking for `ApiReponse` elements *below* the root element, whereas it *is* the root element.

Comment: Since that is the whole document, what should be used instead of .Descendants?

Comment: Is there a way to set a common namespace for all the XDocument, instead of using it in every methods call?

Comment: I'd also like to get a response to this since many of the examples I saw never had a reference to the namespace so I didn't think they were required.

Comment: @Jarek: Why would you bother with a query which can return *multiple* values if it's just the *root*? You could use `doc.Descendants(...)` but if it will always be the root element, that seems pointless.

Comment: @themarcuz: It *is* a common namespace in the whole of the document - but whenever you try to specify an `XName` to find, you need to specify the whole name. You could always extract those names to static readonly variables, which could make it more readable perhaps...

Comment: @JonSkeep I was able to get it to work using .elemetns and referencing the namespace "from r in doc.Elements() select new { Errors = r.Element(ns + "Errors").Value,....". I'm not sure what you mean by saying why would I use a query if it's root, can you expand on that?

Answer (score 0):

I just got Skeeted ;)

Here's something I did in linqpad to get you one of the elements in the XML

```
var myxml = @"<ApiResponse Status=""OK"" xmlns=""http://api.namecheap.com/xml.response"">
<Server>WEB1-SANDBOX1</Server>
<Errors />
<Warnings />
<RequestedCommand>namecheap.domains.check</RequestedCommand>
<CommandResponse>
    <DomainCheckResult Domain=""google.com"" Available=""false"" />
</CommandResponse>

<GMTTimeDifference>--4:00</GMTTimeDifference>
<ExecutionTime>0.875</ExecutionTime>
</ApiResponse>";

//myxml.Dump();

XNamespace p = "http://api.namecheap.com/xml.response";
var doc1 = XElement.Parse(myxml);
var x = from n in doc1.Elements(p + "Server")  select n;
x.First().Value.Dump();
```